# What are some great graduate textbooks with solutions in the back to the problems?

Tags: reference-request, big-list

I can think of Aubin's A Course in Differential Geometry, as well as Knapp's books.
Any other great ones you know of? Especially in the GSM series from AMS (blue and yellow covers).

Comment: Hi, I retagged the question.

Comment: Looks great, thanks!

Comment: Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and Partial Differential Equations by Brezis.  It doesn't have all the exercise solutions, but a great deal of them.  Also there are more advanced problems in the back, again lots with solutions.  A fantastic text.

Comment: Algebraic Number Theory by Richard Mollin has every second question (and is overall quite a nice book).